# Is there a visual web editor based on bootstrap?

Tags: website-design, css, html

Bootstrap is a great framework, and I want know if there is a tool that gives you the possibility of dragging html components, re-sizing and moving them, changing colours, all while generating the bootstrap html code.

I don't want to use Dreamweaver because you need to go and add classes and IDs to the html, which could be a pain sometimes.

Comment: I dont think that hard thing to do specially if you want to use one specific css, the button and all UI component should be pre-styled, thats the only deference and this could save a lot of time

Comment: @DA01 WYSIWYGs are tricky. They keep getting better, but never seem to catch up enough before the web takes a turn and becomes exponentially more complex again. They're at a point where they can work fine for very basic websites that'll run on desktops and laptops, but that seems to be about it.

Comment: finally this seems an answer for what I was looking for http://pingendo.com/

Answer (score 5):

[Jetstrap](https://www.jetstrap.com/) is an online tool that lets you drag-and-drop a large set of official Bootstrap components right to your page.

[image]

They apparently guarantee responsiveness and clean HTML export.

It's free for one project, and $8 for 10 projects.

Comment: This is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com) --  It's a free browser-based editor for Bootstrap HTML, JS and CSS.

- Toolbar with all Bootstrap CSS, Components, and JavaScript
- Preview in full screen or mobile/responsive
- Includes FontAwesome, jQueryUI and other Bootstrap extensions
- Support for Bootstrap 3

**UPDATE**

Bootply now has support for the upcoming Bootstrap 4.

Comment: This looks really great solution

Answer (score 2):

Might it be something like this that you are looking for?

http://www.layoutit.com/

Haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 1):

http://stylebootstrap.info/

http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/

It's not really drag and drop, but these may be a solution to what you are actually trying to solve - an easy way to customize bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this app I developed: [Bootstrap 3 drag'and'drop builder](http://demo.bootstraptor.com/blocks.html)

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a great concept but it's not even in beta and private invite only so its not even released yet for testing so it would be hard to recommend it.

Comment: try free bootstrap templates KIT http://bootstraptor.com/bootstrap-free/ and Bootstrap 3.* premium developer Starter KIT here http://bootstraptor.com

Answer (score 0):

There is the newest Bootstrap visual editor/builder here:

[UMyProto Bootstrap Builder](http://umyproto.com)

It's extremely user friendly, you can edit responsive grid in several clicks, add custom CSS styles, change Bootstrap theme through LESS variables, preview/share/download completed HTML files. And the builder works on tablets!

Comment: It seems  gone for good!

Answer (score 0):

I think that dreamweaver cc 2014 has templates that are very similar to bootstrap that you can use right out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! If you have any questions let us know.

Answer (score 0):

[Pinegrow](http://pinegrow.com/) is another very good option. Helps you with layouts in Bootstrap & Foundation, which you can easily edit in other apps too.